# Reference errors in project in orchard

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I wanted to use **Orchard-Cms** in visual studio, so I cloned its repository from **GitHub** to my local folder. I opened the orchard project from the folder and tried to build the solution but it didn't work. Now I am getting more than 2000 errors. I tried solving this by restoring the packages from nuget package manager but there also i got error saying

> an error occurred while trying to restore packages:Unable to find version '3.2.3' of the package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor'

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Okay it was an easy fix, apparently the feature to restore packages online was turned off, which i turned back on from the nuget package manager window, now its all working.